# Swift - Compiler - other swift flags are not visible to objective c files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, preprocessor

my objective c code is not called because custom flag defined in settings is not visible here. Why? How can I define the same for objc?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the function being called?

Comment: yes, function is called, but not between macro definitions

Comment: The same definitions in swift files working very well.

Comment: it's `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` for objective-c. Look for where is `DEBUG` defined

Comment: So you need TWO settings. One for "Other Swift Flags" and one for "GCC Preprocessor definitions". Note that "Other Swift Flags" should contain just the names without the -D, and for GCC preprocessor definitions I recommend for example -DPLZ=1, so you can use #if in Objective C like in Swift. Without the =1 you need to check with #ifdef.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can put #define's in a header file and include it from Swift, the macros are turned into static variables. Which isn't the same, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift** it is enough to define Custom Flags as:

```
-DMYFLAG
```

for **Objective-C** you need to define Preprocessor Macros:

```
MYFLAG=1
```

[image]

Then in both Swift and ObjC files you can use it like:

```
#if MYFLAG
    //code
#endif
```